# PHP loop through form table and submit data to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, loops, css-tables

Hoping someone can assist with this, been looking at it since the weekend.
I have a form which contains 3 fields (Name, Email, Quarter) and a table with multiple questions (I reduced the code to just 2 questions for illustration purposes.

I want the 3 fields (Name, Email, Number) to be written to the database with question 1 in row 1 and with question 2 in row 2.

Problem is my code only writes the 3 fields (Name, Email, Number) to row 1 (question 1) and writes blanks to row 2 for the 3 fields (Name, Email, Number), the table fields write successfully. What am i doing wrong?

Database View

Name     Email         Number   KPICode   Response  Compliant  Comments
Joe      Joe@test.com   555      k21        yes         yes       test
                        554      k45        no          no        test

HTML Code:

```
        <div class="item form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="hfname">Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Email:</label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <Select type="email" id="email" name="email[]" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <select id="quarter" name="quarter[]" class="form-control">
                        <option>Choose option</option>
                        <option>Q1</option>
                        <option>Q2</option>
                        <option>Q3</option>
                        <option>Q4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead class="headings">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Performance Indicator</th>
                        <th>Response</th>
                        <th>Compliance</th>
                        <th>Notes</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td id="env1" name ="code[]" type="text" scope="row">ENV1</td>
                        <td>1.1 KPI</td>
                        <td>KPI Description.</td>
                        <td><select id="response" name="response[]">
                                        <option>Yes</option>
                                        <option>No</option>
                                    </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><select id="Compliance" name="compliance[]">
                                        <option>Compliant</option>
                                        <option>Partially Compliant</option>
                                        <option>Non-Compliant</option>
                                        </select></td>
                        <td><input id="notes" name="notes[]" role="row" Type="text"></td>
                    </tr>                      
                    <tr>

                        <th id="env2" name="code[]" scope="row">ENV2</th>
                        <td>1.2 KPI</td>
                        <td>KPI Description.</td>
                        <td><select id="response" name="response[]">
                                            <option>Yes</option>
                                            <option>No</option>
                                        </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><select id="Compliance" name="compliance[]">
                                            <option>Compliant</option>
                                            <option>Partially Compliant</option>
                                            <option>Non-Compliant</option>
                                            </select></td>
                        <td><input id="notes" name="notes[]" role="row" Type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

My php code to write the info to the db:

```
foreach($_POST['response'] as $index => $val)
{
$response = $val;
$rfname = $_POST['name'][$index];
$HospitalName = $_POST['email'][$index];
$quarter = $_POST['quarter'][$index];
$kpicode = $_POST['code'][$index];
$compliance = $_POST['compliance'][$index];
$notes = $_POST['notes'][$index];

$sql = "INSERT INTO InfoForm (Name, Email, Quarter, KPICode, Response,  
Compliance, Notes) 
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$quarter', '$kpicode', '$response',
'$compliance', '$notes')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

Comment: Your HTML as posted doesn't have the `response`, `code`, `compliance` or `notes` fields. Can you share more of the HTML? Without the full context we can't really answer the question.

Comment: Output the `POST` (`print_r` or `var_dump`) and see what you are actually working with. You are open to SQL injections as well

Comment: html code updated with missing fields